# Detect a gesture and pass it to a modal view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I've a view controller with a `UICollectionView`. When the user does a long press on a cell, a modal view controller is opened. This second controller has a slider. I'd like the user could interact with the slider without leaving the finger from the screen, like Apple did in Home app when the user interact with dimmable lights.

[image]

I tried to pass the `UIGestureRecognizer` defined for the cell to the slider, but I cannot start the pan, because the gesture recognizer is at `possible` state, while I think it should be at `began` state.

Is there a way to continue a gesture started in a controller in a second one?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not